# Is there a way to disable the touchscreen functionality on the official 7" display that does not also disable all display control functionality?

Tags: display, touchscreen

I have disabled the touchscreen on my official 7" display by adding the below line to my /boot/config.txt

```
    # disable the touchscreen
    disable_touchscreen=1
```

While this works, it also eliminates all ability to programmatically control the display.  Everything under /sys/class/backlight disappears.

Is there a way to disable the touchscreen that will still allow the control of the rest of the display functions?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using your screen with X server (GUI), then you can simply find its ID in the output of `xinput --list` and disable it with `xinput disable <ID>`. Your touchscreen will still generate input events, but your X server will not forward those events to the applications.

You will want to execute the `xinput disable <ID>` command at startup to make the change permanent.

Answer (score 0):

yes indeed it's possible, if I remember correctly there's a pin dedicated to the touchscreen functionality, if you unplug it you'll loose the ability.